# How to replace one character with mutliple characters using search and replace in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, I find myself searching for a character and in command mode doing `x` followed by `10p` or `30p` or something like that fairly often. I was wondering if there is a regular expression version that I could use in the `:s/.../.../` command. `\{m}` work for matching m counts of of characters in the seach, but its equivalent `s/X/X\{10}/gc` replaces with the literal string`X{10}`.

I've been searching the documentation and haven't found out how to do it yet, if anyone knows of a way I'd appreciate knowing about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:h sub-replace-expression` like this

```
%s/X/\=repeat(submatch(0), 10)/gc
```